# Vulkan: trouble understanding cycling of framebuffers

Tags: asynchronous, vulkan

In Vulkan,

A semaphore(***A***) and a fence(***X***) can be passed to `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`. That semaphore(***A***) is subsequently passed to `vkQueueSubmit`, to wait until the image is released by the *Presentation Engine* (PE). A fence(***Y***) can also be passed to `vkQueueSubmit`. Client code can check when the submission has completed by checking fence(***Y***).

When fence(***Y***) signals, this means the PE can display the image.

My question:

How do I know when the PE has finished using the image after a call to `vkQueuePresentKHR`? To me, it doesn't seem that it would be by checking fence(***X***), because that is for client code to know when the image can be written to by `vkQueueSubmit`, isn't it? After the image is sent to `vkQueueSubmit`, it seems the usefulness of fence(***X***) is done. Or, can the same fence(***X***) be used to query the image availability after the call to `vkQueuePresentKHR`?

I don't know when the image is available again after a call to `vkQueuePresentKHR`, without having to call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`.

---

The reason this is causing trouble for me is that in an asynchronous, 60fps, triple buffered app (throwaway learning code), things get out of wack like this:

1. Send an initial framebuffer to the PE. This framebuffer is now unavailable for 16 milliseconds.
2. Within the 16ms, acquire a second image/framebuffer, submit commands, but don't present.
3. Do the same as #2, for a third image. We submit it before 16ms.
4. 16ms have gone by, so we `vkQueuePresentKHR` the second image.
5. Now, if I call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`, the whole thing can fail if image #1 is not yet done being used, because I have acquired three images at this point.
6. How to know if image #1 is available again without calling `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`?

Comment: FYI you can pass a semaphore (B) to vkQueueSubmit to get signaled when the render is done and use pass that semaphore (B) to vkQueuePresentKHR. The fences are not that useful for the base render loop. Only fence Y is useful to allow you to update buffers/textures that the render may be using.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling across this, I believe the statement, "When fence(Y) signals, this means the PE can display the image." is incorrect.

Comment: To elaborate: 

Taken from the spec on `vkQueueSubmit`: "fence is an optional handle to a fence to be signaled once all submitted command buffers have completed execution".

In other words, after submission, the command buffers are moved into the pending state. Once execution has completed, they're moved back into the executable state, where they can be reset (and recycled if you so choose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I know when the PE has finished using the image after a call to `vkQueuePresentKHR`?

You usually do not need to know.

Either you need to acquire a new `VkImage`, or you don't. Whether PE has finished or not does not even enter that decision.

Only reason wanting to know is if you want to measure presentation times. There's a special extension for that: `VK_GOOGLE_display_timing`.

> After the image is sent to `vkQueueSubmit`, it seems the usefulness of fence(***X***) is done.

Well, you can reuse the fence. But the Implementation has stopped using it  as soon as it was signaled and won't be changing its state anymore to anything, if that's what you are asking (and so you are free to `vkDestroy` it or do other things with it).

> I don't know when the image is available again after a call to `vkQueuePresentKHR`, without having to call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`.

Hopefully I cover it below, but I am not precisely sure what the problem here is. I don't know how to eat a soup without a spoon neither. Simply use a spoon— I mean `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`.

> 5. Now, if I call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`, the whole thing can fail if image #1 >is not yet done being used, because I have acquired 3 images at this point.
> 6. How to know if image #1 is available again without calling >`vkAcquireNextImageKHR`?

How is it any different than image #1 and #2?

Yes, you may have already acquired all the images the swapchain has to offer, or the PE is "not ready" to give away an image even if it has two.

In the first case the spec advises against calling `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` with `timeout` of `UINT64_MAX`. It is a simple matter of counting the successful `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` calls vs the `vkQueuePresentKHR`s. One way may be to simply do one `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` and then do one `vkQueuePresentKHR`.

In the second case you can simply call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` and you will eventually get the image.

Comment: Overall, I think the problem stems from another set of learning exercises that I was doing, where I was trying to use multiple queues for drawing each frame. I could not get synchronization to work correctly, and I got the wrong impression of vkAcquireNextImageKHR. In that exercise, that function would fail with an error. But, I know understand, it's because I was acquiring some images without subsequently calling vkQueueSubmit, to release the images back to PE.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use a swapchain image, You need to acquire it. After that the actual availability of the image for rendering purposes is signaled by the semaphore (A) or the fence (X). You can either use the semaphore (X) during the submission as a wait semaphore or wait on the CPU for the fence (X) and submit after that. For performance reasons the semaphore is a preferred way.

Now when You present an image, You give it back to the Presentation Engine. From now on You cannot use that image for whatever purposes. There is no way to check when that image is available again for You so You can render into it again. You cannot do that. If You want to render into a swapchain image again, You need to acquire another image. And during this operation You once again provide a semaphore or a fence (probably different than those provided when You previously acquired a swapchain image). **There is no other way to check when an image is again available than through calling the vkAcquireNextImageKHR() function.**

And when You want to implement triple-buffering, You should just select appropriate presentation mode (mailbox mode is the closest match). You shouldn't wait for a specific time before You present an image. You just should present it when You are done rendering into it. Your synchronization should be entirely based on acquire, present commands and semaphores or fences provided during these operations and during submission. Appropriate present mode should do the rest. Detailed explanation of different present modes is available in [Intel's tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-2).