# Vulkan: Possible to generate secondary command buffers before renderpass?

Tags: vulkan

----------------- ORIGINAL QUESTION ------------------------

In Vulkan,

In order to begin issuing commands to secondary command buffers, is it mandatory to have already acquired the image and have called vkCmdBeginRenderPass() on the primary command buffer?

I'm a noob but that's what it seems like, to me.

------------------------ EDIT #2 --------------------------------

Yes, it is possible to do this:

1. Possibly asynchronously, process logic and record draw-calls in secondary command buffers.
2. Check if secondary command buffers have been recorded: if not, goto #1, else continue.
3. Acquire Image
4. Start primary command buffer; start renderpass.
5. Execute previously recorded secondary command buffers
6. Submit
7. Present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do what I was trying to do, which is to record draw commands to secondary command buffers before having to start recording the primary command buffer.

The problem was two-fold.

1. I wasn't setting the VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_RENDER_PASS_CONTINUE_BIT on the 'flags' member of VkCommandBufferBeginInfo for the secondary buffer.
2. The error from the validation layer was misleading, which said: "No active render pass found at draw-time in Pipeline (0x12)!". This caused me to attempt wrong solutions.

Comment: As for the second bullet - the error is correct. You wanted to draw and You didn't start a render pass. You just forgot to add a proper flag to indicate that the render pass will be started in a primary command buffer (we also didn't know that as You didn't provide us with any source code). 

As for Your sentence - " it is possible [...] to record draw commands to secondary command buffers before having to start recording the primary command buffer." This is exactly what I wrote in my answer. You even must record a secondary cmd buffer before You execute it from a primary cmd buffer.

Comment: @Ekzuzy: The problem lies with me for not explaining the problem correct. The more I learn the lingo of graphics programming, the more I'll be able to state problems clearly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Look at Your question: "is it mandatory to have already acquired the image and have called vkCmdBeginRenderPass() on the primary command buffer?". Are You sure Your answer really answers this question? It explains what was wrong with Your code, why it didn't work. But You asked a totally different question. It's a bit unfair to write a question, expect an answer from a community, then accept Your own answer claiming that You asked a wrong question because You don't know 3D graphics programming "lingo".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what do You mean by "issuing" commands to secondary command buffers and on commands You want to record in those secondary command buffers.

Not all commands can be recorded in secondary command buffers. But there are commands that can be recorded and which don't have anything to do with rendering (and thus with render passes) - data copy, timestamping (timer queries) these are examples. They are not connected in any way with render passes, so they don't require You to start a render pass.

But if You want to record drawing commands, and as You probably know, drawing can only be done from within render passes, then render pass needs to be started already (in the primary command buffer which calls this secondary command buffer).

As for vkAcquireNextImageKHR() function - this function is independent. If by "issuing" You mean recording, then You don't need to call this function. You can record any (valid) commands You want. Recording is just preparing commands for later use, for submission. The same applies to the title of Your question:

> Possible to generate secondary command buffers before renderpass?

I know this is (hopefully) only a bad wording, but You can record any command buffer any time You want. It's the submission that counts and the order of commands recorded in the submitted command buffers. So how do You want to generate a command buffer before a render pass? If You want to record drawing commands and start a render pass, You need a render pass object. If You want to call a secondary command buffer from within a primary command buffer, and if this secondary command buffer draws something, then You need to record a render pass starting command first. After that You can call a secondary command buffer. But this secondary command buffer must be already recorded:

> Each element of pCommandBuffers must be in the pending or executable
>   state.

So You need to record a secondary command buffer first, then You can record a primary command buffer which call this secondary command buffer.

But if You want to submit a command buffer which uses a swapchain image, then this image must be already acquired. As I (and others) have described in Your other question ([trouble understanding cycling of framebuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729735/vulkan-trouble-understanding-cycling-of-framebuffers)
), You cannot submit a command which uses a swapchain image, if this image is not yet acquired. But the submission and image acquiring has nothing to do with command buffer recording. You can record command buffers earlier. You can even pre-record various command buffers for various swapchain images. Again, recording is just preparing commands for later use. The actual usage occurs with submission. So You can only submit those command buffers that use swapchain images which were already acquired.

I hope this helps ;-).

Answer (score 0):

In order to begin recording a secondary command buffer, you must call `vkBeginCommandBuffer` with a `VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo` object. If you want to execute the secondary CB inside of a render pass, you must provide:

1. The `VkRenderPass` object for the pass it will be executed within. Note that this object is *not* the product of `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`.
2. The index of the subpass of the aforementioned `VkRenderPass` that this secondary CB will be executed within.

There is an optional `VkFramebuffer`, which specifies the images you would be rendering to. But as previously stated, this is *optional.* The specification says that providing this data may help performance, but it is optional nevertheless.

So no, there is nothing about secondary CBs that requires that there is an active render pass instance on the primary CB that it will be executed within.

Comment: I thought that this was the case, but when I try to issue vkCmdDrawIndexed on the secondary command buffer, I get the following validation layer error: "No active render pass found at draw-time in Pipeline (0x12)!"

Comment: @Dess: I can only tell you how Vulkan works. If you want to track down a validation layer issue, you need to provide code that reproduces the issue. And since validation is complicated, you have to provide the *entire* code. Or at least the entire code for all relevant objects. Or you can look through the validation layer source code to find that error message and see how it happened. GitHub's search function is terrible, so I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Dess: "*They are neither stupid nor unresearched.*" Your question asks for information that is evident by reading the specification. The parameters passed to begin a secondary command buffer are well-defined and unambiguous. Therefore, there is no reason for you to expect that using secondary command buffers to require any command issued on a primary CB. From your comment, you seem to have a code issue. But you didn't actually *provide the code*, so that someone would be able to tell you what it is. Therefore, your question is unanswerable as stated.

Comment: In the future, if you do understand what the specification says, but your code/validation layers/etc seems to disagree, you should 1) actually say so, and 2) give us that code so that we can help you get it working.